# y-axis units tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, units

I have the following image in my file. How can I add units next to the numbers? I'd like the units to be in volts. I just added a part of the tikz code bellow.

[image]

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=1250,
xtick={\empty},
ymin=4,
ymax=6,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
y unit = \volt
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   5\\
2   4.90000000000009\\
3   5\\
5   5\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the unit in every tick (I would prefer an axis label stating the units, but let's not dispute tastes...), the best option is using `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
    \begin{axis}[%
    xmin=1,
    xmax=5,
    xtick={\empty},
    ymin=4,
    ymax=6,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    yticklabel={\SI[round-mode=places, round-precision=1]{\tick}{V}}
    ]
    \addplot [color=blue, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        1   4.1\\
        2   4.9\\
        3   5\\
        5   5.6\\
    };
\end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

This is explained in section 4.15 of the pgfplots manual, "Ticks Options".

(BTW, this is an example of a Minimal Working Example --- MWE. USe it on your next question! )

(PS, thanks to @Ulrike Fiecher, see [siunitx in pgfplots label description infinite loop?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369871/siunitx-in-pgfplots-label-description-infinite-loop))