# siunitx in pgfplots label description infinite loop?

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx

Answering [y-axis units tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369861/y-axis-units-tikz), I firstly come upon this solution:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
    \begin{axis}[%
    xmin=1,
    xmax=5,
    xtick={\empty},
    ymin=4,
    ymax=6,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    %yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$~V}      %% this works
    yticklabel={\SI{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}{V}}   %% this hangs 
    ]
    \addplot [color=blue, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        1   4.1\\
        2   4.9\\
        3   5\\
        5   5.6\\
    };
\end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That mean, I used `\SI{}{}` in the `yticklabel` key. Unfortunately, this seems to create an infinite loop: the compilations hangs in:

```
[...]
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-bas
ic-dictionary/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg)
```

...and the only way out is interrupting it.

Is it possible to fix this or it's just an operator (me) error?

Comment: Use \tick directly and use the siunitx tools to round the number, e.g. `\SI[round-mode = places,round-precision = 1]{\tick}{V}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks --- it works. Going to update the other answer. If you write this as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `\tick` directly and use the siunitx tools to round the number, e.g. `\SI[round-mode = places,round-precision = 1]{\tick}{V}`

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
    \begin{axis}[%
    xmin=1,
    xmax=5,
    xtick={\empty},
    ymin=4,
    ymax=6,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    yticklabel={\SI[round-mode = places,round-precision = 1]{\tick}{V}}   
    ]
    \addplot [color=blue, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        1   4.1\\
        2   4.9\\
        3   5\\
        5   5.6\\
    };
\end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]